# How to synchronize a Java object with ~100 primitive fields

Tags: java, concurrency

I was asked a question like this during a coding interview:

Suppose you have a Linux machine running multiple Java services - what would be a good way to synchronize a Java object with ~100 primitive fields between these services in real time? Provide at least two solutions and compare the pros and cons of each solution.

Concurrency isn't my strongest point, so thorough explanations would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a sidenote: Real time Java requires a real time JVM such as [JamaicaVM](https://www.aicas.com/cms/en/JamaicaVM). I also don't know how are the primitive fields related to the actual question. I'd you say you need more information (e.g. who writes/reads what).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to do synchronization on the the fields level, but that means that you'll have the corresponding objects to your primitives (e.g. use `Integer` instead of `int`). So, your implementation would look something like:

```
public class SomeSynchronizedClass {

    private Integer field1;
    private Double field2;
    ....

    public void doSomethingWithField1() {
        synchronized(field1) {
            // do something to field1 here
        }
    }

    public void doSomethingWithField2() {
        synchronized(field2) {
            // do something to field2 here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the method is not synchronized since this will hold the lock on the object itself (instance of `SomeSynchronizedClass`), but instead, synchronization is done on each private object (field) so that threads only block when trying to operate on the same field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this is the "best" method, but one option is to persist the object to a database and let the services read/write to that.

With an ORM library like Hibernate, you can use a [`@Version`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) annotation and define a version field that ensures that a service needs to have the latest version of the object before it can be updated. You could also just use database locking.

In terms of pros and cons, you need to think about:

- Will this solution work well when there are lots of concurrent writes?
- Will this solution work well when there are lots of concurrent reads, but not many writes?
- Will this solution work well when most of the writes consist of changes to many of the object's fields?
- Will this solution work well when most of the writes consist of changes to a single field?
- How long will the services need to hold a lock on an object for?

You should consider Hibernate's available locking mechanisms when discussing your answers